# How to get the Kendo control in the viewmodel when using MVVM

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm, kendo-panelbar

I have a simple page with a few controls like this:

```
<div id="ActionMenu">
    <ul id="panelbar"
        data-role="panelbar"
        data-bind="events: { enable: onEnable, collapse: onCollapse }">
        <li id="item1">
            <span>Action menu</span>
            <div>
                <div class="panelActions">
                    <button data-role="button"
                            data-bind="visible: isVisible, enabled: isEnabled, events: { click: onClick }"
                            id="logOutButton">
                        Log users out
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and then I do something like this to create a view model and bind things:

```
var vm;
require(['App/Admin/userInfoGrid'], function (userInfo) {
    vm = userInfo.UserInfoGrid(config_UserInfo);
    kendo.bind($(config_UserInfo.gridId), vm);
    kendo.bind($(config_UserInfo.actionMenu), vm.ActionMenu);
    kendo.bind($(config_UserInfo.logOutButton), vm.LogOutButton);
    kendo.bind($(config_UserInfo.messageWindow), vm.MessageWindow);
});
```

In the page there are multiple controls, so I bind all of them this way.

Inside the vm:

```
  this.ActionMenu = kendo.observable({
            expandMode: "single",
            //onCollapse: onCollapse,
            //onEnable: function(e) {
            //    alert("on enable");
            //}
        });
```

This works, but the panel bar that I am using has it's on methods and events and I want to use those.

So far if I want to use the in-built methods and events inside the viewModel I have to do something like this:

```
var panelBar = $(config.actionMenu).data("kendoPanelBar");
panelBar.enable($("#item1"), false);
```

And if I try to grab and inspect the observable:

```
console.log(that.ActionMenu)
```

It doesn't have the kendo in-built methods, only the ones I have defined myself.

Since I don't want to re-invent the wheel and re-implement all those methods that should be already in place, is there a way to get my ActionMenu to get access to the "kendoPanelBar" functionality?

Since they are, after all, the same control, I would imagine there must be some way I could get it to work like this instead:

```
that.ActionMenu.enable($("#item1"), false);
```

Any ideas?
This particular example is for the panelBar but the same question applies for all other controls.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the best you can do is getting the panelBar once everything is bound, then access from the closure, so you don't have to get it every time; everything else I can think of is more complicated

Comment: Yes, I am sure that would work but some of the functionality I want to implement is inside events in the viewmodel and you define those before it is bound.

Comment: just assign all the widget vars once after you call kendo.bind

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28864906/2001735)